# how can i delete a div that i created with dojo?

Tags: dojo, destroy

i create a div with heading and UL inside with dojo.create. how can i totaly delete this div with heading and UL children so that i can create a div with this id again (with different content)?

I create the div like this (i delete some attributes and the h1 and ul creation because it was too much code, i do it the same way like i create the div):

```
var newAlarmDiv = new dojox.mobile.ScrollableView({
                    id: "divAlarms",
                    dojoType: "dojox.mobile.ScrollableView",
});
newAlarmDiv.placeAt('mobileView','first');
```

i already tried it with the dojo.destroy command but when i create a new div after destroying it i get many different errors so it seems not to be deleted correctly.

How do i correctly "undo" the div creation?

greets
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a "Widget", which has DOM elements associated with it.  If you were destroying only dom elements you would use `dojo.destroy`.

Since you want to destroy the widget, you should use `destroy` or `destroyRecursive`.  The [API Docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/_WidgetBase#destroy) have a good overview of what each method does.

```
var scrollableViewWidget = new dojox.mobile.ScrollableView({/*params*/});
scrollableViewWidget.placeAt('someDiv','first');
scrollableViewWidget.destroyRecursive();
```